# PHP simplexml_load_file vbulletin vaispy permissions redirect

Tags: php, simplexml, vbulletin

Firstly I apologize for the complexity of the title. It was really the best way I could explain the issue.

Basically I am trying to load an external xml. It is part of the vaispy vbulletin mod. The site I am trying to load had permissions set up where if you are not an admin it redirects you to a page where it says

> *Username* you do not have permission to access this page. This could
>   be due to one of several reasons: Your user account may not have
>   sufficient privileges to access this page. Are you trying to edit
>   someone else's post, access administrative features or some other
>   privileged system? If you are trying to post, the administrator may
>   have disabled your account, or it may be awaiting activation

I have proper permissions on said forum, but when I

> $url = "*URL Removed*/vaispy-secret.php?do=xml";
>
> $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
>
> print_r($xml);

I am redirected to the page notifying me I do not have the proper permissions.

How can I log into the vbulletin forums via my php so I will be able to parse the XML properly?

My intentions for this is to create a web app that monitors for certain keywords, and when it finds one immediately sets off an alarm so that link can be moderated.

Comment: You need to establish a session via curl. Which will probably mean writing a script that will do a login.

Comment: I appreciate the lead. Any documentation on session/curl you could send my way would be awesome. I'm pretty nooby yet and any additional help I could get would be excellent!

Comment: Its going to come down to the software itself. If there is an API of sorts, you may be able to authenticate directly. Otherwise what you will need to do is emulate a user. This likely involves posting your credentials a login and preserving the session cookie between requests.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I couldn't get curl to properly work so I went a different route and did it with Applescript/Safari (ick!).